# Bootstrap 3.0's row has margin-left -30px

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Doing upgrade from Bootstrap 2 to Bootstrap 3.0

One of the main changes is that there is no more "row-fluid" and instead, use "row"

However when trying to implement something the below :

```
<div class="widget-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-11">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Subject</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="meetingSubject" name="meetingSubject"
                                   value="<?php echo $meeting->Subject ?>"
                                   autocomplete="off"
                                   placeholder="Meeting Desc">
                        </div>
                    </div>
               <div> 
           </div>
</div>
```

it appear that my label is too near to the left, and when I checked, turns out that row has margin-left -30px. See below image :
[image]

[image]

I don't understand what this is for. Is there any elegant way to fix this with these criteria:

1. Does not change bootstrap core css ( to make it easier to update bootstrap version )
2. Does not make me to repeat the class. ( I am thinking to implement below - but since row is always used everywhere, this solution feels like a bad idea for me )

   ```
    <div class="widget-content">
           <div class="row rowpad30">
           ...
           </div>
    </div>

   .rowpad30
   {
     padding-left: 30px;
     padding-bottom: 5px;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe should you wrap the subdivision in a row :

```
<div class="widget-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-11">
                  <div class="row">   //  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Subject</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="meetingSubject" name="meetingSubject"
                                   value="<?php echo $meeting->Subject ?>"
                                   autocomplete="off"
                                   placeholder="Meeting Desc">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </div> // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

               <div> 
           </div>
</div>
```